# Prove tail series tends to $0$ using contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I want to show that for

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i|  < \infty \tag{1}$$

then for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that

$$ \left| \sum_{i=N}^{\infty} |x_i| \right| = \sum_{i=N}^{\infty} |x_i| < \epsilon. \tag{2}$$

There is already a direct proof which seems more elegant than what I am about to present: [https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tail_of_Convergent_Series_tends_to_Zero#:~:text=%E2%88%9E%E2%88%91n%3DNan%20is%20convergent,convergent%20series%20tends%20to%20zero](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tail_of_Convergent_Series_tends_to_Zero#:%7E:text=%E2%88%9E%E2%88%91n%3DNan%20is%20convergent,convergent%20series%20tends%20to%20zero). However, I just wanted to check that my reasoning is correct.

Suppose that there exists $\epsilon$ such that for all $N$

$$ \sum_{i=N}^{\infty} |x_i| \geq \epsilon. \tag{3}$$

Then this is also true for

$$ \sum_{i=N+k}^{\infty} |x_i| \geq \epsilon \tag{4}$$

for all $k$. Then we can subtract (3) from (4) to obtain $ -(|x_N| + ... + |x_{N+k-1}|) \geq 0$, which implies

$$ \sum_{i=N}^{N+k-1} |x_i| \leq 0. \tag{5}$$

Since this can be derived for all $k$ then we can take the limit as $k \to \infty$ to get

$$ \sum_{i=N}^{\infty} |x_i| \leq 0. \tag{6}$$

Disregarding the trivial case in which the $N$-tail is all $0$'s then this is clearly false.

Now, I tried to the extend this method to the general case, for

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i < \infty. \tag{7}$$

then for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that

$$ \left| \sum_{i=N}^{\infty} x_i \right|< \epsilon. \tag{8}$$

So, analogous to steps (4) and (5) we would have

$$ \left| \sum_{i=N+k}^{\infty} x_i \right| - \left| \sum_{i=N}^{\infty} x_i \right| \geq 0. \tag{9}$$

But the only way I see of bringing the absolute value inside each summation is to use the relation

$$ \sum_{i=N+k}^{\infty} |x_i|  + \sum_{i=N}^{\infty} |x_i|  \geq \left| \sum_{i=N+k}^{\infty} x_i \right| - \left| \sum_{i=N}^{\infty} x_i \right| \geq 0,\tag{10}$$

but that plus sign ruins the structure of the argument.

Comment: $a≥b>0$ and $c≥d>0$ does not imply $a-c≥b-d$. Counterexample: $b=d=1$, $a=2$, $c=3$. Hence implication (3) , (4) to (5) is wrong.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I see. Do you see any way of doing it by contradiction?

Comment: No i don’t. Not any simple one anyway